# Apply an extra filter in view

Tags: attributes, collection, products-view

I am trying to add additional filters to a collection after the collection seems to of been generated. In catalogue product list.phtml there is the following line of code:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

When I `var_dump` this it does report back as a collection (Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection). However if I try to add:

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_handle', array('eq' => 155));
```

directly after the first line, the resulting collection is still exactly the same. How can I modify what is in `$_productCollection` in `list.phtml`?

Any help is appreciated

---- UPDATE ----

I notice that in the List.php block the collection is loaded in the `_beforeToHtml` method:

```
$this->_getProductCollection()->load();
```

I am assuming therefore I have to "unload" (?) it and then apply my filters in the view and then re-load it (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `$collection->clear()`, apply your filters, and then reload the collection. However IIRC the collection will be in a different state than the layer model expects.

This a combination of both `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::clear()` and `Varien_Data_Collection::clear()`.

Comment: Seems to work for what I am trying to do. Fantastic! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter product collection before loading. See following, your config.xml

```
<frontend>   
       <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <ssd_ajaxify>
                        <class>SSD_Ajaxify_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                    </ssd_ajaxify>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
</frontend>
```

And Observer.php:

```
class SSD_Ajaxify_Model_Observer
{    
public function catalogProductCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
        {
            $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
            $path    = implode('_', array(
                $request->getModuleName(),
                $request->getControllerName(),
                $request->getActionName(),
            ));
            if ($path == 'catalog_category_view') {
                $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('price', array('gt'=> 50));
            }
        }
}
```

By the way this affects to your toolbar and layered navigation, and also product list in category view page.

Comment: `$path = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()` might be a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

By using rewrite Magento Product List Block, we can add an extra filter in product collection.

```
Please use below link for reference:-
[http://shariqnasir.blogspot.in/2011/06/override-core-modules.html][1]
[http://pratikkhamar.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/magentooverride-block/][2]
```

Hope this will help you.